# In Google Forms when responses move to the linked Google Sheet, date values are changed to string. How to preserve the date format?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have a date question in a Google form. Responses shown in Google Forms are recognized to be dates as I can see the summary in the responses grouped by month.

[image]

But When they show up in the linked Google Sheet, it has converted them to strings with a ` before the first number and leading zeros trimmed.

[image]

Because of this, I am not able to sort the column properly.

Is there any way to preserve the date format when it is carried over to the linked Google sheet as well?

Comment: Maybe the best would be keep the raw results from G Forms and transform/clean them with some functions in G Sheets

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot replicate your situation of ``But When they show up in the linked Google Sheet, it has converted them to strings with a ` before the first number and leading zeros trimmed.``. When "Date" item is added to Google Form and submitted it, it seems that the value from "Date" item is a date object on the linked Spreadsheet. But, I would like to understand your situation. So, can I ask you about the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current issue? First, I would like to understand your question correctly.

Comment: @Tanaike Thank you. I have added some screen shots. Does that make my question clearer?

Comment: Thank you for replying and updating your question. From your updated information, I proposed an answer. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*One way is to `include year` component in the **form** since it looks from the screenshot that its now set to `month/day`. you'll be able to **sort** (the column) within the connected google sheet once you have the full date format style*

[image]

Comment: I swear I did this and the result was the same! Honest! Well, when I put the year back in, you're right. It fixes it. Thank you. Sheesh.

Answer (score 1):

From your added information and `Is there any way to preserve the date format when it is carried over to the linked Google sheet as well?`, how about using the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet linked with your Google Form. And save the script. And, [please install the OnSubmit trigger to this function `onSubmit`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#manage_triggers_manually).

```js
const onSubmit = ({ range }) => range.setValues(range.getValues());
```

- When you submit your Google Form, the submitted values are retrieved by `getValues` and put into the same range by `setValues`. By this, `'` of the 1st character is removed, and `'11/23` is converted to `11/23` of a date object.
- The above modification uses this year (2023) to the converted date object. If you want to use another year, how about the following sample script?

  ```js
  const onSubmit = ({ range, source }) => {
    const columnNumber = 2; // This is from your added image.
    const offsetYear = 2024; // Please set your value.

    const values = range.getValues()[0];
    values[columnNumber - 1] = Utilities.parseDate(`${offsetYear}/${values[columnNumber - 1]}`, source.getSpreadsheetTimeZone(), "yyyy/MM/dd");
    range.setValues([values]).offset(0, columnNumber - 1).setNumberFormat("M/d"); // or "MM/dd"
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I see there's a whole world in the Google spreadsheet script editor that I can tap into. Much to learn!